# Не запускается MongoDB на Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Я установил Ubuntu 18.04 на сервер, но после перезапуска каждый раз монга перестаёт работать (систему переустанавливал раз 6 и каждый раз такая петрушка была)). Помогите пожалуйста)

---

Ошибка:
root@vh3757:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.16
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-02-21T21:13:39.881+0300 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такое решение. 
1) Сначала удалить файл .lock
`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock` 
2) отремонтировать mongodb
`mongod -–repair`
3) запустить сервер mongod
`sudo service mongod start` 
4) запустить клиент Монго
`mongo`

Так же проверьте в конфурационном файле данные. 
`sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf`
Проверить, что установлены параметры:

```
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017
```

Перезапустите mongo

```
sudo service mongodb restart
sudo service mongod restart
```

Ну и запустите mongo

```
mongo
```